VSTO Cannot save the attachment. Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided
My VSTO plugin intercepts attachments, however there's a case that when I attempt to intercept attachments (on-send) from the explorer or inspector that I receive the error at the very end. The logic is entirely the same for Explorer and Inspector attachment handling, it looks as:
currentMail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(tempfile);

The error is:
Cannot save the attachment. Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided.

Now I suspect this is related to the email being in use (by Outlook), as I am able to trigger the same code if I modify it as a draft first, save it and then send the email.
What does error code -2147467259 represent though?
More of the error:
Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
ErrorCode   -2147467259 int
HResult -2147467259 int
HelpLink    null    string
InnerException  null    System.Exception
Message "Cannot save the attachment. Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided."   string
Source  "Microsoft Outlook" string
StackTrace  "   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile(String Path)\r\n   
TargetSite  {Void SaveAsFile(System.String)}    System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}

Edit: If I Save() the mailitem before calling that code, the error does not trigger anymore? I modified the code to only save the mailitem in case I detected if it's 'dirty' (modified subject, body, recipients, attachments). However for performance reasons I do not want to call unecessarily mailitem.Save() (as the entire mailitem + attachments are synced with Exchange).

Is it under the cache mode in Outlook? How do you add an attachments? Does the attachment represent a file on the local system?

You may also try to check the attachment type first.
The Attachment.Type property returns an OlAttachmentType constant indicating the type of the specified object. Note, it has a new value which represents a link to the OneDrive storage.
OlAttachmentType == 7
That is a new web attachment type (OneDrive).

Hi, thanks for the suggestion. So this happens if the user clicks reply. The attachments in question are embedded images (present because of email signature). However, if I save the mailitem.Save() and then execute the attachment.SaveAs(...) I do not get that error anymore. It works, but when for example you have a lot of attachments present, the mailitem.Save() will cause the item to upload to whatever mailserver is in the back-end as a draft. Which I want to limit (Outlook literally freezes up on its own). The Mailitem.Saved variable is not reliable to determine if you should save or not.

It seems you are using the non-cached mode in Outlook with Exchange. Try to enable the cached mode which Microsoft recommends in case of any issues over the non-cached one. Let me know whether it helps or not.

Hi Eugene, I am using cached mode unfortunately (1y cache). That is why I cannot explain myself on what is happening. The email itself was from the same day.
